# What is the difference between the input/backing dataset and the writeback dataset in Phonograph?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

The Phonograph2 API appears to support an input/backing dataset and a writeback dataset. What's the difference between these?

Answer (score 3):

The input/backing dataset is the primary source of data for the Table in Phonograph2.

Users can post edis to the Table via Phonograph2 API.

The writeback dataset is the materialized view of these edits applied on top of the input/backing dataset.

Importantly, Phonograph2 doesn't apply these edits directly to the input/backing dataset. So, any dataset-based analysis which needs to take edits into account should use the writeback dataset.