# Data sync between ontology and writeback

Tags: palantir-foundry

how sync works in between writeback and ontology dataset.
we are updating writeback dataset using typescript function. in most of the cases it is taking update but in few cases its not working.

I have build whole pipeline, but problem remains same. everyday it is taking old data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short (best-guess): You need to build the writeback-dataset to see the changes propagated from the ontology to the writeback-dataset.

##### Details

A few notes:

- A backing dataset is what defines one object types's structure, and its rows becomes object instances
- Once you have an object type populated with object instances, by default, those are read only.
- Once you enable "edits"/"writeback" on this object type, and depending on the configuration you set, you will be able to create/edit/delete/... objects via API or/and via [Foundry Action](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/getting-started/) (which itself might call a [Foundry Function](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/getting-started/)).
- A writeback dataset is a dataset that writes the current state of one object type's instances as rows, whenever it builds.

So, trying to guess the case you are in:

- Your object is ready and has edits/writeback enabled.
- You trigger an Action that runs a Function, which creates or edits objects
- You look at the dataset and it does not contain the edits you just made

In this case, your edits are "present" in the objects (you can confirm that by using [object explorer](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-explorer/getting-started/) for instance), and you need to build the writeback-dataset in order for the current state of the objects to be written as rows.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558830/what-is-the-difference-between-the-input-backing-dataset-and-the-writeback-datas) might be useful as well.